# Family tree with mother and father (or parent couple)

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, charts, tree

I need to create a family tree graph (not exactly as the image 1, but similar) which SHOULD contain father and mother  (or any other) relation,.

On image 2 you can see a organizational chart, which solve partially my problems, but I have not the "couple" relation. `Father - Mother` / `Grandfather - GrandMother`, instead of `parents`, for instance. I need the "parent" block to be two blocks interconnected, one the "mother" and another "father" (or any relationed couple).

Currently I have seen a lot of organizational charts ([Google Chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/orgchart?csw=1#Example) or [jOrgChart](http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4151695/html/jOrgChart/example/example.html), for instance) but not a "family" tree.

Can you suggest a library, script,  how-to, idea, or whatever to solve this?

(sorry if this is confusing. If need aditional info to help-me solve this, ask on comments)

[image: image 1]

[image: image 2]

Comment: Could you show us the code you used to make the organizational chart from the second picture?

Comment: @jsve This is not my code, in particular. I can do this with [Google Chart](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/orgchart?csw=1#Example), or  [jOrgChart](http://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/4151695/html/jOrgChart/example/example.html), for instance.

Comment: for organizational : do you have large number of data to be display..?like i have made org chart with over a 100k data without browser crasing issue see the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22007087/best-way-to-draw-organization-chart-using-javascript-over-100k-nodes

Comment: @YashPatel I need a family tree chart, not a organizational. This is the problem. All the charts I can see have not "parent" separated so, is a adaptiation of organizational chart use..

Comment: @GabrielSantos but if you have managed parent n child relation through database Id than you can adapt any of org chart script N rest is done using css that you have mention in your second image

Comment: @YashPatel In a organizational chart, a first level entry can have only a second-level relation, not a first - first (lik married people) with a first - second (childs), so, I can't use the organizational chart or can't figure your suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you to use JavaScript and jQuery widget BasicPrimitives, more info [here](http://www.basicprimitives.com/). It has the features you need and can show many-to-many relationships.

Answer (score 0):

here is code sample of how to implement family diagram based on relations between people.

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>The very first family chart</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="demo/js/jquery/ui-lightness/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="demo/js/jquery/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="demo/js/jquery/jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.min.js"></script>

    <script  type="text/javascript" src="demo/js/primitives.min.js?219"></script>
    <link href="demo/css/primitives.latest.css?219" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
        $(window).load(function () {
            var options = new primitives.famdiagram.Config();

            var items = [
                { id: 1, title: "1", description: "", image: "demo/images/photos/m.png" },
                { id: 2, title: "2", description: "", image: "demo/images/photos/f.png" },
                { id: 3, title: "3", description: "",image: "demo/images/photos/m.png" },
                { id: 4, title: "4", description: "", image: "demo/images/photos/f.png" },
                { id: 5, parents: [1, 2], title: "5", description: "", image: "demo/images/photos/m.png" },
                { id: 6, parents: [3, 4], title: "6", description: "", image: "demo/images/photos/f.png" },
                { id: 8, parents: [5, 6], title: "8", description: "", image: "demo/images/photos/m.png" },
                { id: 7, parents: [5, 6], title: "7", description: "7", image: "demo/images/photos/f.png" },
                { id: 9, title: "9", description: "", image: "demo/images/photos/f.png" },
              { id: 12, title: "12", description: "", image: "demo/images/photos/m.png" },
              { id: 10, parents: [8, 9], title: "10", description: "", image: "demo/images/photos/m.png" },
              { id: 11, parents: [8, 9], title: "11", description: "", image: "demo/images/photos/f.png" },
              { id: 13, parents: [7, 12], title: "13", description: "", image: "demo/images/photos/m.png" },
              { id: 14, parents: [7, 12], title: "14", description: "", image: "demo/images/photos/f.png" }
            ];

            options.pageFitMode = 0;
            options.items = items;
            options.cursorItem = 2;
            options.linesWidth = 1;
            options.linesColor = "black";
            options.hasSelectorCheckbox = primitives.common.Enabled.False;
            options.normalLevelShift = 20;
            options.dotLevelShift = 20;
            options.lineLevelShift = 20;
            options.normalItemsInterval = 10;
            options.dotItemsInterval = 10;
            options.lineItemsInterval = 10;

            options.defaultTemplateName = "info";
            options.templates = [getInfoTemplate()];
            options.onItemRender = onTemplateRender;

            jQuery("#basicdiagram").famDiagram(options);
        });//]]>  


        function onTemplateRender(event, data) {
            switch (data.renderingMode) {
                case primitives.common.RenderingMode.Create:
                    /* Initialize widgets here */
                    break;
                case primitives.common.RenderingMode.Update:
                    /* Update widgets here */
                    break;
            }

            var itemConfig = data.context;

            if (data.templateName == "info") {
                data.element.find("[name=title]").text(itemConfig.title);
            }
        }

        function getInfoTemplate() {
            var result = new primitives.orgdiagram.TemplateConfig();
            result.name = "info";

            result.itemSize = new primitives.common.Size(80, 36);
            result.minimizedItemSize = new primitives.common.Size(3, 3);
            result.highlightPadding = new primitives.common.Thickness(4, 4, 4, 4);


            var itemTemplate = jQuery(
              '<div class="bp-item bp-corner-all bt-item-frame">'
                + '<div name="title" class="bp-item" style="top: 3px; left: 6px; width: 68px; height: 28px; font-size: 12px;">'
                + '</div>'
            + '</div>'
            ).css({
                width: result.itemSize.width + "px",
                height: result.itemSize.height + "px"
            }).addClass("bp-item bp-corner-all bt-item-frame");
            result.itemTemplate = itemTemplate.wrap('<div>').parent().html();

            return result;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="basicdiagram" style="width: 640px; height: 800px; border-style: dotted; border-width: 1px;" />
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Comment: but in primitives - can i add ex-wife / ex-husbent in a tree? via @DenFrop

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>The very first family chart</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-1.10.2.custom.min.js"></script>

    <script  type="text/javascript" src="primitives.min.js"></script>
    <link href="primitives.latest.css" media="screen" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

    <script type='text/javascript'>//<![CDATA[ 
        $(window).load(function () {
            var options = new primitives.famdiagram.Config();

            var items = [
                { id: 4, parents: [1,2], title: "4", description: "Дочка",image: "images/photos/m.png" },
                { id: 3, parents: [1,2], title: "3", description: "Сынок",image: "images/photos/m.png" },
                { id: 2, title: "2", gender: "M", description: "Мари", image: "images/photos/f.png" },
                { id: 1, title: "1", label: "SeR", gender: "M", description: "Серж", image: "images/photos/m.png" }
            ];

        var annotations = [
            new primitives.famdiagram.HighlightPathAnnotationConfig({
            items: [1, 2,1],
            color: primitives.common.Colors.Red,
            lineWidth: 2,
            opacity: 1,
            showArrows: true
        })
        ];

        function Update() {
           control.update(primitives.orgdiagram.UpdateMode.Refresh);
            };


            //DemoVerticalLayout.html
            options.pageFitMode = primitives.common.PageFitMode.None;  //Page Fit Mode
            options.orientationType = primitives.common.OrientationType.Bottom;  //Orientation Type
            options.verticalAlignment = primitives.common.VerticalAlignmentType.Top;
        options.horizontalAlignment = primitives.common.HorizontalAlignmentType.Center;
        options.childrenPlacementType = primitives.common.ChildrenPlacementType.Horizontal;
        options.leavesPlacementType = primitives.common.ChildrenPlacementType.Horizontal;
            options.hideGrandParentsConnectors = "false";
            options.hasButtons = primitives.common.Enabled.Auto;
            options.groupTitleVerticalAlignment = primitives.common.VerticalAlignmentType.Middle;
            options.groupTitleHorizontalAlignment = primitives.common.HorizontalAlignmentType.Center;
            options.items = items;
            //options.annotations = annotations;
            options.cursorItem = 5;
            options.linesWidth = 1;
            options.linesColor = "black";
            options.hasSelectorCheckbox = primitives.common.Enabled.False;
            options.normalLevelShift = 20;
            options.dotLevelShift = 20;
            options.lineLevelShift = 20;
            options.normalItemsInterval = 20;
            options.dotItemsInterval = 10;
            options.lineItemsInterval = 10;
            options.arrowsDirection = primitives.common.GroupByType.Children;
            options.elbowType = primitives.common.ElbowType.Round;
            options.showExtraArrows = false;

            options.defaultTemplateName = "info";
            options.templates = [getInfoTemplate()];
            options.onItemRender = onTemplateRender;

            jQuery("#basicdiagram").famDiagram(options);
        });//]]>  


        function onTemplateRender(event, data) {
            switch (data.renderingMode) {
                case primitives.common.RenderingMode.Create:
                    /* Initialize widgets here */
                    break;
                case primitives.common.RenderingMode.Update:
                    /* Update widgets here */
                    break;
            }

            var itemConfig = data.context;

            if (data.templateName == "info") {
                data.element.find("[name=label]").text(itemConfig.label);
                data.element.find("[name=title]").text(itemConfig.title);
                data.element.find("[name=title]").attr("title", itemConfig.title);
                data.element.find("[name=description]").text(itemConfig.description);
            }
        }

        function getInfoTemplate() {
            var result = new primitives.orgdiagram.TemplateConfig();
            result.name = "info";

            result.itemSize = new primitives.common.Size(180, 80);
            //result.minimizedItemSize = new primitives.common.Size(3, 3);
            //result.highlightPadding = new primitives.common.Thickness(4, 4, 4, 4);


            var itemTemplate = jQuery(
              '<div class="bp-item bp-corner-all bt-item-frame" style="height: 119px; top: 6px; left: 145.5px; position: absolute; padding: 0px; margin: 0px;">'
            + '    <div class="bp-item bp-corner-all bp-title-frame" style="top: 2px; left: 2px; height: 20px;">'
            + '        <div name="title" class="bp-item bp-title" style="top: 3px; left: 6px; height: 18px;">Manager E</div>'
            + '    </div>'
            //+ '    <div class="bp-item bp-photo-frame" style="top: 26px; left: 2px; width: 50px; height: 60px;">'
            //+ '        <img name="photo" style="height:60px; width:50px;" src="images/photos/m.png">'
            //+ '    </div>'
            + '    <div name="phone" class="bp-item" style="top: 26px; left: 56px; height: 18px; font-size: 12px;">1-900-800-70-15</div>'
            + '    <div class="bp-item" style="top: 44px; left: 56px; height: 18px; font-size: 12px;">'
            + '        <a name="email" href="mailto:mail1@mail.com?Subject=Hello%20world" target="_top">mail1@mail.com</a>'
            + '    </div>'
            + '    <div name="description" class="bp-item" style="top: 62px; left: 56px; height: 36px; font-size: 10px;">Managers E description </div>'
            + '</div>'
            ).css({
                //width: result.itemSize.width + "px",
                height: result.itemSize.height + "px"
            }).addClass("bp-item bp-corner-all bt-item-frame");
            result.itemTemplate = itemTemplate.wrap('<div>').parent().html();

            return result;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="basicdiagram" style="width: 640px; height: 600px; border-style: dotted; border-width: 1px;" />
</body>
</html>
```

Result:

[image: result screen]

Comment: please add explanatory notes so that the OP can *understand* the code you've provided, and apply it to the question they have asked